# Opening redis connection is too slow

Tags: connection, timeout, redis, booksleeve

It sometimes takes very long time to open connection to Redis. Looks like it depends on connecting thread's count and, maybe, PC configuration. I run test for 50 threads on two workstations with 4-core CPU's, and it takes 70-100ms to open connection, and on 8-core workstation and 8-core staging server it took 1000-1500ms and sometimes much more. Strange dependency, but it' reproductible.
When IIS application pool restarts, and all threads are trying to reconnect, it causes something like cache downtime. What I have to change to get reasonable connection time?

I use BookSleeve client, and here is code sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        threads.Add(new Thread(RunThread));

    foreach (var thread in threads)
        thread.Start();

    foreach (var thread in threads)
        thread.Join();
}

static void RunThread()
{
    var connection = TryGetConnection();
    while (connection == null)
    {
        connection = TryGetConnection();
    }
}

static RedisConnection TryGetConnection()
{
    var connection = currentConnection;
    if ((connection != null) && (connection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.Open))
        return connection;

    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        if ((currentConnection != null) && (currentConnection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.Open))
            return currentConnection;

        if ((connectionTask != null) && connectionTask.IsCompleted)
            connectionTask = null;

        if (connectionTask == null)
        {
            if ((currentConnection != null) && (currentConnection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.Closed))
            {
                currentConnection.Dispose();
                currentConnection = null;
            }

            if (currentConnection == null)
            {
                currentConnection = new RedisConnection(
                    serverAddress,
                    serverPort,
                    ioTimeout: (int) operationTimeout.TotalMilliseconds,
                    syncTimeout: (int) operationTimeout.TotalMilliseconds);
            }

            if (currentConnection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.New)
                currentConnection.Open();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: :) I've edited original post

Comment: What exact version of booksleeve are you using? This matters, because the IO layer has changed quite significantly between versions.

Comment: 1.3.37, the latest version from NuGet

Comment: @MarcGravell 1.3.37, the latest version from NuGet

Answer (score 2):

Let's look; we have a loop here:

```
var connection = TryGetConnection();
while (connection == null)
{
    connection = TryGetConnection();
}
```

it is *not* clear to me that `TryGetConnection` is correctly handling all scenarios ("opening", etc), but frankly, it is a moot point : if you are going to do a tight loop until you get a connection, you might as well simplify significantly. The first thing you could do would be to *wait* on the task (with a timeout, obviously), rather than using a hot loop. Generalizing:

```
var task = connection.Open();
connection.Wait(task);
```

The `Wait` in the above uses the connection's specified timeout, and does some work to simplify exceptions for you.

However, in this *specific* case, you could probably just use something like:

```
var connection = TryGetConnection();
// no loop here
```

with:

```
static RedisConnection TryGetConnection()
{
    var connection = currentConnection;
    if ((connection != null) && (connection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.Open))
        return connection;

    lock (syncRoot)
    {   // double-checked
        if ((connection != null) && (connection.State == RedisConnectionBase.ConnectionState.Open))
            return connection;

        connection = ConnectionUtils.Connect(config);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

where `config` is a composite of the values; basically something like:

```
myserver:6389,syncTimeout=1000
```

This configuration string can also be more complex, including multiple redis servers (master/slave etc), a service-name (for use with sentinel), a client-name (for use with `client list`), etc.

I *suspect* some of the complexity in your method is leading to some extra looping at the moment. See if it is any more reliable with the above.